# Проблема с сериализацией DataTable через XmlSerializer

Tags: wcf, soap, сериализация

В WCF-службе есть следующий `OperationContract`:

```
[SoapRpcMethod(Use=SoapBindingUse.Literal)]
[OperationContract(Action = "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/OrdersByPassport")]
[WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
string OrdersByPassport(int passport);
...

public string OrdersByPassport(int passport)
{
    Repository repository = new Repository();
    Query_result qr = new Query_result();
    qr.data = repository.GetOrdersByPassport(passport);
    Type t = qr.GetType();
    SOAP_Serializer s = new SOAP_Serializer(t);
    s.Serialize(qr);            
    return (s.GetText());
}
```

Этот `OperationContract` работает с DLL, в которой описаны классы:

```
public class XmlTypeMapping_init
{
    protected XmlTypeMapping tm;
    public XmlTypeMapping_init(Type t)
    {            
        tm = (new SoapReflectionImporter().ImportTypeMapping(t));  
    }
}

public class SOAP_Serializer:XmlTypeMapping_init
{
    private StreamWriter file;
    private StreamReader file_out;
    private XmlSerializer xml_s;

    public SOAP_Serializer(Type t)
        : base(t)
    {
        xml_s = new XmlSerializer(tm);
    }

    public void Serialize(Object obj)
    {
        using (file = new StreamWriter("Temp_file.txt"))
        {
            xml_s.Serialize(file, obj);
        }
        file.Close();
    }
    public string GetText()
    {
        string s;
        using (file_out = new StreamReader("Temp_file.txt"))
        {
            s = file_out.ReadToEnd();                
        }
        file_out.Close();            
        return(s);
    }
}
```

При вызове `OperationContract` появляется ошибка:

> Тип System.Data.DataTable невозможно сериализовать с сообщениями, закодированными как SOAP. Установите для своего сообщения свойство Use равным Literal.

Как избавиться от этой ошибки?

Comment: Возможно, установить _для своего сообщения свойство Use равным Literal_

Comment: Каким образом? Сообщение формирует XmlSerializer.

Comment: А почему вы сериализируете `DataTable` вручную? Почему бы не положить её в контракт?

Comment: Класс, содержащий поле с типом DataTable (Query_result), является контрактом данных WCF-службы. Но в таком виде данные не пересылаются, поэтому я решил сначала сериализовать их, приведя к надлежащему виду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас падает не их-за того, что вы используете `XmlSerializer`. А из-за того, что используемый метод построения маппинга - `SoapReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping` - не поддерживает маппинг типа `System.Data.DataTable`.

Например:

```
public class SomeContract
{
    public DataTable Table { get; set; }
}

Type t = typeof(SomeContract);
// падает вот на этой строчке, вообще не доходя до создания XmlSerializer
var tm = (new SoapReflectionImporter().ImportTypeMapping(t));

var xml_s = new XmlSerializer(tm);
```

А если выбросить `SoapReflectionImporter` (он вам, судя по всему, не нужен) и просто сериализовать контракт как XML, то работает:

```
Type t = typeof(SomeContract);
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(t);
```

P.S. И да, работать через файл - плохая идея. Хотя бы потому, что она не срабатвывает при одновременных вызовах. Вообе весь ваш `SOAP_Serializer` стоит выбросить и заменить на что-то вроде

```
public static class Serializer
{
    public static string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        var resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        using (var writer = new StringWriter(resultBuilder))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        }

        return resultBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

А еще лучще - не возвращать `DataTable` на сторону клиента. Сделать конкретный специализированный контракт - ради этого и существует SOAP и WCF.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Лучше использовать в качестве контракта данных что-то более конкретное, например контейнер? DataTable выглядит предпочтительно с точки зрения универсальности.

Comment: @AN90 вот именно из-за универсальности он и не сериализуется нормально - в нем может быть вообще все что угодно.